# Maximum of trivial function $(y-x^T\beta)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $y\in{\mathbb R}$, $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and $\beta\in B\subset {\mathbb R}^n$, where $B$ is compact and convex. Is there a simple expression for $\max_\beta (y-x^T\beta)^2$, for arbitrary $x\neq0$ $y\neq0$?

Sorry if this is trivial but I just can't see it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I meant maximum. It is involved in an upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not expect a simple expression. You are asking for the two support hyperplanes for $B$ that are orthogonal to $x.$ If $B$ is not convex, it is possible that a support hyperplane intersects $B$ in more than one point, but that will not change $y - x^T \beta$ or   $(y - x^T \beta)^2$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane

Comment: OK, suppose convexity.

Comment: @Mono if the boundary is smooth, the whole thing is Lagrange multipliers; this is standard but I would not call it closed form. Compare when $B$ is a polyhedron, the maximum could easily occur at a vertex.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion.